# Is a socket a stream

Tags: node.js

Using [rx-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-node) library, I expect this code to work. But it doesn't recognize a `socket` as a `stream`,

```
stream.pause();
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
```

even though the `net` documentation appears that it is.

How do I get the `stream` portion of a `net.createServer()`

```
var RxNode = require('rx-node');
var server;
var sSocket;

server =  net.createServer(function (socket) {
  sSocket = socket;
});

var subscription = RxNode.fromStream(sSocket, 'ondata')
    .subscribe(function (x) {process.stdout.write("Got data " + x + "\n"); });

server.listen(xxxxx, 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with rx-node, but I would assume that `var subscription = ...` needs to be in `net.createServer` callback function, otherwise `sSocket` is still an undefined variable by the time that code runs.

Comment: it's not about "recognition", the error clearly states there is no such defined variable at the moment, you need to either fix order of your code or declare variable

Comment: Jekrb you are right.

Comment: How do I rearange my code so that subscription can be outside createServer?

Comment: @Ivan: You can't. You just need to get used to it.

Comment: @Ivan: Almost all questions that ask "how can I write my code outside of the callback" will be marked as duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. Those that are not will be marked as duplicate to other similar questions.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Then how do I make an observer of an observable in a different module ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, socket is a stream. The problem you get is not that it is not a stream but that it is undefined. See the docs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket

> Class: net.Socket#
>   Added in: v0.3.4
>   This object is an abstraction of a TCP or local socket. **net.Socket instances implement a duplex Stream interface**. They can be created by the user and used as a client (with connect()) or they can be created by Node.js and passed to the user through the 'connection' event of a server. [emphasis added]

When this:

```
stream.pause();
```

gives you this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
```

it means that `stream` is undefined, not that it is not a stream.

In your case the `stream` is most likely the `sSocket` variable that you pass to `RxNode.fromStream()` which is obviously undefined just by looking at the code. The order of evaluation is something like:

```
var sSocket; // (1)

server =  net.createServer(function (socket) { // (2)
  sSocket = socket; // (4)
});

var subscription = RxNode.fromStream(sSocket, 'ondata') // (3)
```

so as you can see you are trying to use it before it gets defined.

Now, how to use it after it is defined? You need to use it inside of the `net.createServer()` callback, or in some function started after that callback has fired.

Another problem with your code is that the function that you pass to `net.createServer()` is a `connectionListener` which is automatically set as a listener for the 'connection' event and you seem to be using it as if it was something else. See the examples in the documentation:

- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener

It is pretty much exactly the same as what you are trying to do.